# Laravel 10 password reset always returns Please wait before retrying

Tags: laravel

I'm using Laravel Breeze for auth scaffolding. I'm customizing the password reset a little bit so that I can use my own emails:

In the `User` model:

```php
public function sendPasswordResetNotification($token): void
{
    $url = route('password.reset', ['token' => $token, 'email' => $this->email]);

    $message = (new ResetPassword($url))->onQueue('email');
    Mail::to($this->email)->queue($message);
}
```

In the `ResetPassword` Mailable:

```php
public function build()
{
    return $this->subject('Reset password - '.config('app.name'))
        ->from(config('app.contact_email'), config('app.name'))
        ->markdown('mail.user.reset-password', [
            'url' => $this->url,
        ]);
}
```

This all works nicely and the link the email goes to the right route.

But whenever I reset a password for a user, it always (even on the first try) returns the error: "Please wait before retrying."

This seems to be related to throttling however I have not customized anything there. In config/auth:

```php
'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
        'throttle' => 60,
    ],
],
```

Comment: It looks ok but can you show more code?

Comment: What would you like to see?

Comment: Do you have any custom code? When the issue happens? When you submit the reset password form? or when you click the reset password links sent to the email?

Comment: No custom code. The error happens when I submit the reset password form.

Comment: Turns out that I used the wrong route for the form submit... This was interesting as it looked like it was working but with a validation/throttle error, while it was posting the form content to the wrong controller.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you may accidentally set rate limit in somewhere in your application.

1 . Try checking in your service providers, such as RouteServiceProvider

```
protected function configureRateLimiting(): void
{
    RateLimiter::for('api', function (Request $request) {
        return Limit::perMinute(60)->by($request->user()?->id ?: $request->ip());
    });
}
```

2. Try checking in PasswordResetLinkController